# High altitude balloon, GPS issues: programmed reset

Tags: scripting, gps, reset

How might I insert a programme code to prompt a repeating reset in a ublox7max using a serial script. My ublox delivers gibberish if it is disturbed, but sorts itself out after a manual reset. Since a manual reset will not be possible in flight, I would like to know how to slip a line into the programme that will prompt a regular reset. I seem to recall seeing a comment somewhere along the lines that this may be possible.

I should say that I know very little about electronics or programming and am on a very steep learning curve.

Colin.

Comment: You need to inform us of your environment. What kind of hardware/software are you using. There is a reset pin on the chip and that needs to get a specific voltage and it will reset. That you can do in many ways. One way is using PIC or Microcontroller like arduino.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, are you sure it is on the ublox side? I never saw one chip (ublox or other) that deliver wrong data for more than some seconds.